# How to get cell content from WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the specific cell data from `datagrid`.

This is my source code:

```cs
public bool Query(DataGrid dg, string sql, string constr)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
                {
                    CommandText = sql,
                    Connection = con
                };
                OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //cmd.Parameters.Add();
                dg.ItemsSource = rd;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); return false; }}


_SQL.Query(datagrid, sql, constr2);
string s = (datagrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(datagrid.Items[0]) as TextBlock).Text;
```

I am sure that there is data in the `datagrid` however the resulting string is null. What am I missing?

Comment: That's a ... very un-WPF-y way of doing things. You should be data binding that `DataGrid`, and in whatever snippet the shown code is, access the value from your model or view model.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Thanks for answering.I'm a beginner for WPF. Can you please show me how to bind data from access database?

Comment: Please start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) then jump over to [data templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and [styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0).